# How to dynamically override list_filter fields in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have several fields in `list_filter`. I have to create a generic `model.SimpleListFilter` that is called for every value in `list_filter`.

I cannot create individual class for every list_filter.

The best solution would be something like:

```
class MyModelAdmin(MyCustomFilter):
    list_filter = ('client_name', 'case_received_date')`
```

The `lookups` and `queryset` method in `MyCustomFilter` gets called for each `list_filter` field.

```
# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client_name','client_application_number')
    list_filter = ('client_name', 'case_received_date', MyCustomFilter)

class MyCustomFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):    
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        pass

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # Apply the filter selected, if any
        pass
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function to generate an infinite number of anonymous classes. Here's an update to your code:

```
class MyCustomFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        pass

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # Apply the filter selected, if any
        pass

def my_custom_filter_maker(field):
    class MyAnonymousCls(MyCustomFilter):
        title = field
        parameter_name = field

    return MyAnonymousCls

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client_name','client_application_number')
    list_filter = ('client_name', 'case_received_date', 
        my_custom_filter_maker('field_name'),  my_custom_filter_maker('another_field'))
```

Comment: That seems like a better solution. But the best solution would be something like: `class MyModelAdmin(CustomFilter):
    list_filter = ('client_name', 'case_received_date')` The `lookups` and `queryset` method in `CustomFilter` gets called for each `list_filter` field.

Comment: Glad that worked - would you mind accepting my answer, if I helped you solve your problem? Thanks!